# some method and class name color changed to blue! how to restore

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I working on android studio 2.2 preview 1.for some reasons that I don't know, all brackets , prentices and methods name color changed to blue. How I can restore it. i change my theme to default and restore to it to dracula but it does not work.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to Settings --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts --> Code and manually updating it there.